# How can I sort elements with same value

Tags: javascript, html

For example:

```
<div id="aphaOrder">
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">olark</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">snapengage</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">helponclick</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">hangouts</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">atlass</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">hipchat</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">chat hip</div>
</div>
```

I want to keep only those divs whose `data-key` attribute is "key1", other ones should be removed.
I don't know how to start. I think I should use append to "aphaOrder" but ...
Sorry for bad English...

Comment: What needs to be sorted? You mention sorting in the title but not the description

Comment: @TedBrownlow data-key to keep only this div where data-key is "key1"

Comment: That’s not sorting. It’s filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const $mainContainer = document.getElementById('aphaOrder');
for (const nodeElement of $mainContainer.childNodes) {
  if (nodeElement.getAttribute && nodeElement.getAttribute('data-key') === 'key1') {
    $mainContainer.removeChild(nodeElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="aphaOrder">
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">olark</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">snapengage</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">helponclick</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">hangouts</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">atlass</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">hipchat</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">chat hip</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! is there any way that i can bring back removed childs?

Comment: You can store the removed ones and insert back when want to..

Answer (score 0):

Select all the divs and look at the sata attribute. If it is not the one you want, remove it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#aphaOrder div").forEach(div => div.dataset.key!=="key1" && div.remove());
```

```html
<div id="aphaOrder">
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">olark</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">snapengage</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">helponclick</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">hangouts</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">atlass</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">hipchat</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">chat hip</div>
</div>
```

---

What I first thought you wanted was to sort all the elements....

1. So you select the elements
2. Convert it to an array
3. Compare the data attribute, if same sort text
4. If data attribute different sort by data attribute
5. Append the elements back into the document.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector("#aphaOrder");
const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#aphaOrder div"));

divs.sort((a,b) => {
  const aKey = a.dataset.key;
  const bKey = b.dataset.key;
  if ( aKey === bKey) {
    return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
  } 
  return aKey.localeCompare(bKey);
});

divs.forEach(div => wrapper.appendChild(div));
```

```html
<div id="aphaOrder">
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">olark</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">snapengage</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key1">helponclick</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">hangouts</div>
    <div class="value"  data-key="key2">atlass</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">hipchat</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-key="key3">chat hip</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not trying to sort, but to filter, keeping only the other ones. You can select all the matching elements and then delete them:

```js
const elementsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll("#aphaOrder > [data-key=key1]");

for (const element of elementsToRemove) {
  element.parent.removeChild(element);
}
```